# VS2008 attaching a debugger (C++) to handle assert(...)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, assert

There are two scenarios that I'm interested to improve in my assert.
1) a debug build app is started regularly, if there is an assertion I'm getting "Debug assertion failed" dialog box with "Abort", "Retry", "Ignore". Abort and Ignore answers are working fine. The problem with Retry. If I hit retry I'm getting that useless "Application error, breakpoint has been reached" "OK" - to terminate, "Cancel" - to debug the program.

Is it possible to avoid this dialog and go directly to the "Just in time debugger" dialog that shows choices for debuggers? I understand that the "Application error" dialog box is triggered by `__debugbreak()` or `_asm int 3` on intel, so after "Retry" was pressed I need to attach debugger without using _asm int 3. Is this possible? I couldn't find any WinAPI that does this

2) A debug build app is started in VS debugger (using F5). If an assert is triggered I don't want to see any dialog, I want it to stop right on the assert. I managed to install crt debug runtime hooks and if IsDebuggerPresent then I __debugbreak() and it stops on the line of the assert. It works perfectly when I'm debugging windows mobile builds, but I'm still getting a dialog box for Win32 builds: "APP.exe has triggered a breakpoint", "Break", "Continue", and greyed out "Ignore". Any way to completely disable it?

Comment: Doesn't help, sorry. What's wrong with the question or you are just bored to write spam comments??

Comment: What's wrong with the question is that it is mostly a rant.  The actual question is very well disguised.  Plus the answer to your question, if there is one, lies within the implementation of assert() itself.  What code does it call?  You have the source code.  You can step in to it as easily as anyone.  When you do you'll probably find that it will be very difficult or even impossible to circumvent what annoys you, to the point where it's probably best to  just relax and click through the second dialog box.  Hence the admittedly snarky "warm milk" comment.

Comment: It's not a rant and it's targeted to people who may know the answer or who have the same problem as me (multiple useless messageboxes). I know how assert implemented in ms crt from bottom to the top and I use my own implementation with extra changes (using debug hooking api). That's why if you pay more attention in case [2] I have only one dialog - I don't have the same behavior as in case [1].

Comment: There is some behavior that seems to be implemented inside kernerl itself, and that's the kernel itself that handles int 3 and shows that message box: "Application error, breakpoint has been reached", then if you click OK, the kernel itself check settings (or list of registered JIT debuggers and shows you the dialog box and when you choose a debugger, the kernel invokes debugger... technically that logic could be implemented in the app itself, but that's overkill probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the registry entry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug.

I think that if you set Auto to 1, that the debugger is automatically started.

And of course changing the assert implementation can also help you (take a look at the SuperAssert of John Robbins from his famous Debugging Windows Applications book).

Comment: Thanks Patrick, that's exactly what I was looking for, now I don't get that annoying "Application error, breakpoint has been reached" dialog box.
I redefine my own assert, ASSERT, ATLASSERT etc maro this way:

#define assert(_expr) ((void)( (!!(_expr)) || (assert_function(#_expr, __FILE__, __LINE__)&&(__debugbreak(),0)) ))

assert_function is similar in implementation to _wassert or whatever function used in ms crt, but in my function I check if IsDebuggerPresent then I don't show any dialogs and break right on the line where assert is located instead of breaking inside some crt function

Comment: I know about SuperAsser, but I don't need anything from it. I use similar technique to get stack backtrace for memory leak detection, but in assert I don't find it to be useful, especially if I can attach with debugger and see what's wrong.
The only thing that remains to be fixed is the "APP.exe has triggered breakpoint" dialog box.
__debugbeak(); on PC builds trigger this dialogbox, but if you debug Windows Mobile code then I don't have this box and I'd like to find out how to skip it in pc build as well.

Comment: Documented in [Enabling Postmortem Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/enabling-postmortem-debugging).